# ActiveRecord - Get the last n records and delete them in one command?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

Hello all and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

The question is really explained in the title.

I tried Model.last(n).destroy_all but none of that would work.

I was wondering if it is possible to do it in one line, and if not what would be the cleanest way of doing it?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To do it in one SQL query use `delete_all`:

```rb
Model.order(created_at: :desc).limit(n).delete_all
```

**But `delete_all` won't execute any model callbacks or validations**

To run callbacks and validations use `destroy_all`:

```rb
Model.order(created_at: :desc).limit(n).destroy_all
```

Unfortunately `destroy_all` will execute n + 1 SQL queries: 1 query to retrieve records and n queries to delete each record.

Comment: Hey Ivan. Thanks for your answer. I will only be allowed to accept your answer in 2 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: No it's not one sql query. I tried this on Ruby 2.0.0p253 && Rails 4.0.2 and here is the result: https://gist.github.com/pinepara/8433912 @Dragan

Comment: @IvanDenisov Do you mean use `delete_all` instead of `destroy_all`? Hate to say this but no again. `delete_all` doesn't support limit scope.

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this by:

`Model.last(n).each(&:destroy)`

@IvanDenisov points out another way to do this:

`Model.order('created_at DESC').limit(n).destroy_all`

It's basically doing the same thing according to [Rails API Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all), but a little bit verbose. Besides, **it doesn't do all things in one SQL query.**

---

**Detailed comparison of SQL queries**

I tried to run both codes in `rails console` under Ruby 2.0.0p253 && Rails 4.0.4, here are the results:

```
2.0.0p353 :002 > Role.last(3).each(&:destroy)
  Role Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" ORDER BY "roles"."id" DESC LIMIT 3
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.5ms)  DELETE FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1  [["id", 5487]]
   (11.8ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1  [["id", 5488]]
   (5.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1  [["id", 5489]]
   (4.6ms)  COMMIT

2.0.0p353 :004 > Role.order('created_at DESC').limit(3).destroy_all
  Role Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 3
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1  [["id", 5492]]
   (6.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1  [["id", 5491]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1  [["id", 5490]]
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
```

The `DELETE` parts are **exactly the same**. They both took multiple SQL queries.

The only difference is `SELECT` part, if we change `'created_at DESC'` to `'id DESC'`, they will be **exactly the same** too.

Comment: @IvanDenisov The rails document says that `destroy_all` 'Destroys the records matching conditions by instantiating each record and calling its destroy method.' So it's basically doing exact the same thing. Refer to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all